# Get specific lines from a huge text file

Tags: performance, perl

I had a 50 GB text file (about 45 million lines) and needed to extract about 1500 lines from it. I knew their indices, that is, line numbers. Those 1500 lines were spread across the whole file up to the very end. To accomplish this, I wrote a simple Perl script. It worked and was quite fast: it finished in about 4-5 minutes on a low-end "business" laptop (but with an SSD).

**Question 1**: Is the code sensible and well-written?
**Question 2**: Could the performance be improved somehow?

```perl
#!/bin/perl
# 
# Get lines from a file using line numbers from a second file
# Syntax
# getlinesfromfile.pl <source-file> <index-file> <output-file>
#
# Index file contains line numbers, one per line
# Example:
#
# 1
# 5
# 17
# 73
# 31337

use strict;
use warnings;

my $version = "1.0.4";
my $date_released = "4 December 2019";
print "\nGet lines from file. Version $version released on $date_released\n";

my ($source_file, $idx_file, $output_file) = @ARGV;
if (not defined $source_file or not defined $output_file or not defined $idx_file) {
    print "Parameters missing. Usage:\n\t$0 <source_file> <idx_file> <output_file>";
    exit;
}

open(my $i_fh, '<', $source_file)
    or die "FAILED to open '$source_file'!";
open(my $idx_fh, '<', $idx_file)
    or die "FAILED to open '$idx_file'!";
open(my $o_fh, '>', $output_file)
    or die "FAILED to open '$output_file'!";

# Read in indices
$/ = "\r\n";
my %indices;
while (my $line = <$idx_fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    $indices{$line} = 1;
}
close $idx_fh;
my $count_indices = scalar keys %indices;

my $msg_intro = <<"END";
Input filename: '$source_file'
Index filename: '$idx_file'
Output filename: '$output_file'

Indices: $count_indices

END

print $msg_intro;

my $lines_found = 0;
my $lines_parsed = 0;
$/ = "\n";
while (my $line = <$i_fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    $lines_parsed++;
    if (defined $indices{$lines_parsed}) {
        print $o_fh $line, "\r\n";
        $lines_found++;
    }
}
close $o_fh;
close $i_fh;
print ("Parsed $lines_parsed lines, found $lines_found matches.\n");
```

Comment: Use `$.` instead of `$lines_parsed`.

Comment: For efficiency, after the highest index line is found, print and exit 0. No need to read the rest of the file. This is true if the highest index is frequently much less than the total number of lines, so it makes sense to spend the time on testing if we are done.

Comment: Use somewhat more descriptive names for these vars, e.g., `$in_fh`, `$out_fh`.

Comment: Make the filenadle stand out more, for readability: `print { $out_fh } $line, "\r\n";`

Comment: For performance, you might try transforming the indices into a simple sed program, and `exec`ing that.  It's unlikely to make much difference, though, as most of your overhead is probably in the filesystem rather than in user-space.

Comment: Pffff @TimurShtatland "For efficiency, after the highest index line is found, print and exit 0" - this is so obvious, how could I have missed it? :) Thank you for pointing that out to me (and for the rest of the advices)!

Comment: print "Parameters missing. Usage:\n\t$0 <source_file> <idx_file> <output_file>"\n;

Answer (score 5):

I know this might be a one time task, however, if you want to create a reusable code, I would always put the line counting code in a "continue" block. It is more readable and safer for future enhancements. Somehow the line increment code "finds itself" pushed after a next statement...

```
while (my $line = <$i_fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    if (defined $indices{$lines_parsed}) {
        print $o_fh $line, "\r\n";
        $lines_found++;
    }
} continue {
    $lines_parsed++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the comments on the question and the other answer,
here are some other adjustments for you to consider, mainly for coding style.

---

You could format your header comments as plain old documentation
([POD](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod)):

```
=head1 DESCRIPTION

Get lines from a file using line numbers from a second file

Syntax

    getlinesfromfile.pl <source-file> <index-file> <output-file>

=cut
```

This gives you manpage-like help with [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc):

```
perldoc getlinesfromfile.pl
```

---

Since it is hard for most people to remember all of Perl's special
variables, like [$0](https://perldoc.perl.org/variables/$0), it is
a good practice to use the [English](https://perldoc.perl.org/English)
module:

```
use English;
```

`$0` becomes `$PROGRAM_NAME`

`$/` becomes `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`

---

The command line argument checking can be simplified by
checking the number passed:

```
if (@ARGV != 3) {
    die "Parameters missing. Usage:\n\t$PROGRAM_NAME <source_file> <idx_file> <output_file>\n";
}
my ($source_file, $idx_file, $output_file) = @ARGV;
```

---

Give the user more information when `open` fails by displaying.
`$OS_ERROR` (aka, `$!`):

```
or die "FAILED to open '$source_file': $OS_ERROR\n";
```

---

Move the `open` calls closer to the `while` loops that they
are used with.

---

The `$msg_intro` variable is not needed; just print the here-doc
directly.  Also,
[END](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END)
has special meaning.  It would be better to use something like
`EOF` instead:

```
print <<"EOF";
Input filename: '$source_file'
Index filename: '$idx_file'
Output filename: '$output_file'

Indices: $count_indices

EOF
```

---

It is simpler to omit the parentheses from this `print`:

```
print "Parsed $lines_parsed lines, found $lines_found matches.\n";
```

---

Here is new code with the suggestions above:

```
=head1 DESCRIPTION

Get lines from a file using line numbers from a second file

Syntax

    getlinesfromfile.pl <source-file> <index-file> <output-file>

Index file contains line numbers, one per line

Example:

    1
    5
    17
    73
    31337

=cut

use strict;
use warnings;
use English;

print "\nGet lines from file. Version 1.0.4 released on 4 December 2019\n";

if (@ARGV != 3) {
    die "Parameters missing. Usage:\n\t$PROGRAM_NAME <source_file> <idx_file> <output_file>\n";
}
my ($source_file, $idx_file, $output_file) = @ARGV;

# Read in indices
$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\r\n";
my %indices;
open(my $idx_fh, '<', $idx_file)
    or die "FAILED to open '$idx_file': $OS_ERROR\n";
while (my $line = <$idx_fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    $indices{$line} = 1;
}
close $idx_fh;
my $count_indices = scalar keys %indices;

print <<"EOF";
Input filename: '$source_file'
Index filename: '$idx_file'
Output filename: '$output_file'

Indices: $count_indices

EOF

my $lines_found = 0;
my $lines_parsed = 0;
$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\n";
open(my $i_fh, '<', $source_file)
    or die "FAILED to open '$source_file': $OS_ERROR\n";
open(my $o_fh, '>', $output_file)
    or die "FAILED to open '$output_file': $OS_ERROR\n";
while (my $line = <$i_fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    $lines_parsed++;
    if (defined $indices{$lines_parsed}) {
        print $o_fh $line, "\r\n";
        $lines_found++;
    }
}
close $o_fh;
close $i_fh;
print "Parsed $lines_parsed lines, found $lines_found matches.\n";
```